# Relation between absolute magnitude of UV and star formation rate

Tags: star, galaxy, mass, star-formation, formation

I surfed the internet and searched a lot of sites,
so far I got this

[image]

but unable to find the formula which relates only M<sub>uv</sub> and the Ψ as I don't know the value of parameters A<sub>uv</sub> and μ(z).

If there exists any such formula, then do help!

Comment: Explain all the terms please.

Comment: Hi space_nkc, I don’t know if you saw it, but I edited my answer after you accepted it, to give a simpler relation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UV luminosity of a galaxy can be calculated, given a stellar population. This population, in turn, can be calculated given an *initial mass function* (IMF), i.e. the distribution function of stellar masses. In this case, the UV luminosity should be linearly proportional to the star formation rate (SFR), sometimes written $\Psi$.

The UV is primarily emitted by young stars with lifetimes of $\lesssim10^8\,\mathrm{yr}$. Assuming that the SFR is constant over longer time scales, [Kennicutt (1998)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998ARA%26A..36..189K) calculates in his seminal paper (with ~5000 citations) for a [Salpeter (1995)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1955ApJ...121..161S) IMF (equally seminal; ~6700 citations) with mass limits 0.1 and 100 $M_\odot\,\mathrm{yr}^{-1}$ that
$$
\frac{\Psi_\mathrm{Sal}}{M_\odot\,\mathrm{yr}^{-1}} = 1.4\times10^{-28}\frac{L_\nu}{\mathrm{erg}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}\,\mathrm{Hz}^{-1}}.
$$
were $L_\nu$ is the emitted UV luminosity *density*, i.e. luminosity per frequency bin. At a (luminosity) distance $d_L$ from the galaxy, the observed flux density $f_\nu$ is then
$$
f_\nu = \frac{L_\nu}{4\pi d_L^2}.
$$

The flux density is related to the apparent (observed) UV magnitude $m_\mathrm{UV}$ as ([Oke & Gunn 1983](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1983ApJ...266..713O); ~1900 citations despite their +/- error in their most important equation)
$$
m_\mathrm{UV} = -2.5\log \frac{f_\nu}{\mathrm{erg}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}\,\mathrm{cm}^{-1}\,\mathrm{Hz}^{-1}} - 48.6.
$$

#### Distance modulus and dust extinction

The apparent magnitude is related to the absolute magnitude $M$ through the distance modulus
$$
\mu \equiv m - M.
$$

Furthermore, the above relations don't take into account the fact that some of the emitted light is absorbed by dust. Dust extinction *increases* the observed magnitude (because magnitudes are backwards) by a number $A_\mathrm{UV}$.

That is, the apparent UV magnitude is
$$
m_\mathrm{UV} = M_\mathrm{UV} + \mu + A_\mathrm{UV}.
$$

Typically, the extinction $A_\mathrm{UV}$ isn't measured explicitly (because UV measurements are difficult); rather the extinction is measured in two optical bands, e.g. $B$ and $V$. The extinction $A_\lambda$ at a given wavelength $\lambda$ can then be estimated as
$$
A_\lambda = k_\lambda E(B-V),
$$
where $E(B-V)\equiv A_B - A_V$ is the color excess, and $k_\lambda$ is given by the assumed extinction law, e.g. a [Cardelli (1989)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1989ApJ...345..245C) law or a [Calzetti (2000)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000ApJ...533..682C) law.

#### The role of the initial mass function

The Salpeter IMF is old, and at that time we didn't have too good data for the low-mass stars (which are faint), so he just fitted a single power-law. With better data, it was eventually found that there were less low-mass stars than previously thought, i.e. it takes less stellar mass to produce a given UV luminosity. A popular choice today is the [Chabrier (2003)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003PASP..115..763C) IMF (~5100 citations), which gives *roughly* a factor of 1.8 more UV than the Salpeter IMF per star formed, on average. That is, the conversion factor is 1.8 times smaller.

With a Chabrier IMF, you hence get that the relation between absolute magnitude of UV and star formation rate (which is what you're asking) is
$$
\frac{\Psi_\mathrm{Cha}}{M_\odot\,\mathrm{yr}^{-1}} = 7.8\times10^{-29}\,\times\,4\pi d_L^2 \times10^{-(M_\mathrm{UV} + \mu + A_\mathrm{UV}+48.6)/2.5},
$$
where $d_L$ is measured in cm.

#### Simpler relation

The above formula resembles the one you give, but is a bit strange in that it both contains $\mu$ *and* $d_L$, which are just two different measures of the same thing. Using the definition
$$
\mu = 5\log\left(\frac{d_L}{10\,\mathrm{pc}}\right)
$$
we can — after [a bit of algebra](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/ff7310fa-e363-4486-80e1-0b38c2489588/3103e43bd0ad772c/res/1b8b415d-2107-4bcd-9a16-0a49b2609a61) — express the definition of the Oke & Gunn (AB) magnitude as
$$
M_\mathrm{UV} = -2.5\log L_\nu + 51.6.
$$
With this, we can can write the relation as
$$
\frac{\Psi_\mathrm{Cha}}{M_\odot\,\mathrm{yr}^{-1}} = 7.8\times10^{-29}
\,\times
10^{-(M_\mathrm{UV}+A_\mathrm{UV}-51.6)/2.5},
$$
or even
$$
\boxed{
\frac{\Psi_\mathrm{Cha}}{M_\odot\,\mathrm{yr}^{-1}} = 3.4\times10^{-8}
\,\times
10^{-(M_\mathrm{UV}+A_\mathrm{UV})/2.5}.}
$$

Comment: @RobJeffries Hmm… yeah, maybe… But the title asks for the relation between _absolute_, not apparent, magnitude and SFR, so the way I interpreted this is that they found that formula, but didn't know what the terms meant. But I agree it's a somewhat peculiar formula, so I'll edit to give a simpler form.